# How to access a function parameter from another function in swift

Tags: swift, function, parameters

Right now this is my code: 
My problem is that I need to access pollText1Button in my didTapVoteButton2 function and the pollText2Button in my didTapVoteButton function.

(If you need to see the code that I cut of of this post to provide an alternative solution to my problem I can provide that as well)

Any help is appreciated greatly!

extension HomeViewController: YourPollsCellDelegate {

```
func didTapVoteButton2(_ pollText2Button: UIButton, pollNum: Int, cell: YourPollsCell)  {

     // code

    }


func didTapVoteButton(_ pollText1Button: UIButton, pollNum: Int, cell: YourPollsCell) {

     // code

}
```

Comment: You really should post more code than this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outlet to access your other buttons.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var voteButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var voteButton2: UIButton!

    func didTapVoteButton2(_ pollText2Button: UIButton, pollNum: Int, cell: YourPollsCell)  {
        // code
        voteButton1.setTitle("some other label", for: .normal)
    }


    func didTapVoteButton(_ pollText1Button: UIButton, pollNum: Int, cell: YourPollsCell) {
        // code
        voteButton2.setTitle("some other label", for: .normal)
    }
}
```